# Show that $\mathcal{M}(\mathrm{SU}(2))\cong S^{3}$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, manifolds, lie-groups

Show that $\mathcal{M}(\mathrm{SU}(2))\cong S^{3}.$ $\mathcal{M}$ here is the
underlying manifold of the group.

**What I tried:**

To show we need to establish a diffeomorphism between them.

The special unitary group $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ can be represented as a group of $2\times2$ complex matrices with determinant $1$ and unitary elements. Let $U$ be an element of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, and it can be written as:

$ U = \begin{bmatrix} a & -\overline{b} \\ b & \overline{a} \end{bmatrix} $

where $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers satisfying $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$ (due to the unitary condition).

Now, let's define a map $\phi: \mathrm{SU}(2) \rightarrow S^3$; $ \phi(U) = (a, b) \in \mathbb{C}^2 $.

This is where I'm stuck. Is this correct so far? How can I continue further?

Comment: When you say 'let's define a map', I don't understand the rest of that sentence. You didn't define the map. To do so, you need to describe where each matrix in $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ is sent to in $S^3$.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Ok, but how exactly do I describe it, I am having a problem figuring this thing out.

Comment: Often these kinds of questions can be resolved by recalling the definitions involved. In this case you have done half of that: you have the definition of $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ written down, what about that of $S^3$?

Comment: I have found it is $S^3=\left\{(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}^2:\left|z_1\right|^2+\left|z_2\right|^2=1\right\}$. Do I just write the map as $\phi(U)=(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}^2$, where $z_1 = a$ and $z_2 = b$? This map takes an element $U$ from $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and assigns it a point $(z_1, z_2)$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$. I don't see how it helps for me

Comment: $S^3=\{(w,x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^4|w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Comment: @Arbatus If what you have written is the definition of $S^3$ that you are using in this context, then your map is fine. However, I suspect that the map you're after is really
$$
\phi \pmatrix{a & -\bar b\\
b & \bar a} = (\text{Re}(a), \text{Im}(a), \text{Re}(b), \text{Im}(b)).
$$